# BigQuery returns 404 error on table that exists

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404   
NOT_FOUND 
{ 
   "code" : 404, 
   "errors" : [ { 
     "domain" : "global", 
     "message" : "Not found: Table   
optimizehit.com:optimizehit-db:_026b772272a27a80bf416f682c0426cbb2061afe.anon1d35b89ee725c18278192da78ee38f63d0b749ca", 
 "reason" : "notFound" 
   } ], 
   "message" : "Not found: Table   
optimizehit.com:optimizehit-db:_026b772272a27a80bf416f682c0426cbb2061afe.anon1d35b89ee725c18278192da78ee38f63d0b749ca" 
}
```

We are getting this error while querying a table that always exists in our dataset, so it's not a problem of the table missing as per the documentation of the error code.

Checking the dashboard also showed that the table exists, and querying it after a minute or so, it was working.

There is, however, a cron that updates this table with a query job with

> writeDisposition set to WRITE_TRUNCATE.

Could this affect querying the table?

> Edit: The time of this error was: August 5, 2015 at 6:48:39 PM UTC+5:30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're receiving the "not found" error not on the table `FROM` which you query, but instead on the anonymous table to which you are writing:

`optimizehit.com:optimizehit-db:_026b772272a27a80bf416f682c0426cbb2061afe.anon1d35b89ee725c18278192da78ee38f63d0b749ca`

As a BigQuery engineer, I looked into the history of this anonymous table and the jobs that operated on it. The job that would have used this anonymous table failed with a `RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` error.

The `configuration.query.destination_table` fields would still contain the anonymous table reference the job would have filled with results. Did you check for an error result before retrieving the query job results?

Comment: Now it makes sense. The query is extracting results first to the anonymous table, but if the rate limit is exceeded, it would fail. But from the error logs, I could only assume it was because somehow BigQuery couldn't reference the correct table. Thanks!